# Html canvas spotlight region over image

Tags: html, image, canvas

am looking for a solution to realize a spotlight on a html canvas which draws an image. I darkened the complete image with:

```
context.globalAlpha = 0.3;
context.fillStyle = 'black';
context.fillRect(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
```

This works fine. Now I want to remove the darkening effect on a specific rectangle area. How can I do this without calculation of the "surrounding" rectangles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Redraw a region of original image

You can simply draw back the image with the specified rectangular region you want to "reveal":

```
 /// reset global alpha and then
 context.globalAlpha = 1;

 context.drawImage(image, rx, ry, rw, rh,
                          rx, ry, rw, rh)
```

Here you pick first the source rectangle (first line), then the destination rectangle. If width and height (`rw` and `rh`) are different the source region is scaled to fit the destination region. If the image size is 1:1 both source and destination would be the same (as in this example).

### Clipping

As an alternative you can use clipping instead:

```
/// to remove clipping properly save current state
context.save();

/// define region you want to clip
context.beginPath();
context.rect(rx, ry, rw, rh);

/// set clip
context.clip();

/// draw the image as the original
context.drawImage(image, x, y);

/// remove clipping
context.restore();
```

**[ONLINE DEMO SHOWING THESE TWO TECHNIQUES](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/AxQUh/)**

### Alternatives

Composite modes (`globalCompositeOperation`) allow clipping as well but would not be useful here as you would still need to draw with a region of the original image and therefor you can just draw it directly (as in first example).

Another way could be to use two canvases where you draw the image on the bottom canvas and the mask on the top canvas. Then punch a hole in the top canvas. If you want to animate/move around the mask this can be a good solution.